# How to test music.listens?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, spotify

I'm trying to figure out how to use music.listens open graph api. Here's steps I did

1. Open Spotify app and then play a music then shared that music on facebook.
2. login to facebook.com then navigate to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
3. then get access token from the page.
4. access https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAIcvJFBXTz9Io9DlhF59TTbusrBjGto7ZCce783D1CSHkBgsknGZB2xubQNiEg6ZBxO1GZCpMZCGbJCsFAJKPNmUQU70uGQZDZD

but it always returns empty.

Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Don't make duplicate questions. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10760014/music-listen-returns-an-empty-array

Comment: @phwd  If you/someone can explain exactly why this is a dupe then I'll close it as such.

Comment: @Kev it's in the first paragraph of the linked question "I'm currently using music.listen open graph api, but it returns an empty data for most of users." compared to above which is using the same music.listen endpoint (call/action) which returns empty. The answer in the linked question says the same thing I said below as well. Basically Igy answered the sub question within his [linked](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10760014/music-listen-returns-an-empty-array) which the OP is currently asking again for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: @phwd // I was going to ask my questions over there, but that question already has a marked answer. Beside that, I never mentioned that I used access_token on that question. It makes a huge difference. I agree with you that this is very very very similar question, but not exact question.

Comment: since..you're the only one who answered it, I vote for close too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `me/music.listens` endpoint provides data for the current application. Not all applications.

Only if you have the given permission, `user_actions.music` will you be able to access all applications. Without it, you can only access the current application actions.

Comment: Is there an api that returns data for all the applications? If there's none, what's the point of friends_music.listens and friends_music:listens permissions?

Comment: @Moon clarified, you didn't mention whether you gave the permission or not.

Comment: FYI, I signed up spotify and listened to musics on spotify app

Comment: @Moon That access token you got was from an application (not Spotify), the application doesn't automatically get permissions to your Spotify activities, you need to grant it.

Comment: // ah..great..so I need to have permission to access my own activities..got it! I will try and report back! Thank you so much for your time !!!!